# What does the following sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

[image]

Specifically,what does the line "which all the rooms opened off" mean.Does the hallway have these doors which were open?

Comment: It means that the hallway had a door connecting it directly to every room in the house.  "The room opens off of this hallway" means "there is a door from the hallway into this room"; the sentence states that every room in the house had this property.

Comment: Even if it says the rooms *'opened_off'* the hallway, it doesn't mean that the doors were left open.

Comment: It a slightly strange twist on the idiomatic "the room opened off the hallway/ballroom/whatever", meaning that the main access to the room was through a doorway coming from that space.  Has nothing to do with whether the door is open or closed, or whether there even is a door in the doorway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that the hallway contained entrances to all the rooms; each room could be entered via the hallway.

[image]

*^ It would probably look similar to this.*